# how to customize UserCreationForm in django

Tags: python, django, forms, customization

Hi I am trying to clean up my usercreationform using widgets but its not working. The class is not being passed 'form-control' It does however work for model form. Not sure what I am doing wrong? I am new.

forms.py

> ```
> class ProfileForm(UserCreationForm):
>   class Meta:
>     model=User
>     fields = ('email', 'avatar', 'password1', 'password2')
>
>     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
>      super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>
>      self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
>      self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
>      self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
>
> class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
>  class Meta:
>     model = Customer
>     fields = ['name','email','phone_number' ]
>     widgets={
>     'name' :forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
>     'email' :forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
>     'phone_number' :forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ProfileForm(UserCreationForm):
 class Meta:
    fields = ('email', 'avatar', 'password1', 'password2')
    model = User

email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email',
                                                            'class': 'form-control',
                                                            }))

avatar = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Avatar',
                                                            'class': 'form-control',
                                                            }))
password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password',
                                                            'class': 'form-control',
                                                            }))
password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm Password',
                                                            'class': 'form-control',
                                                            }))

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['password2'].label = "Confirm Password"
```